# Launching OpenMPI/pthread apps with slurm

Tags: mpi, openmpi

On Cray computers such as an XE6, when launching a hybrid MPI/pthreads application via aprun there is a depth parameter which indicates the number of threads each process can spawn.  For example,

```
aprun -N2 -n12 -d5
```

Each process can spawn 5 threads which the OS will distribute.

Is there a similar option when launching OpenMPI/pthread applications with Slurm's srun?  The machine is a generic HP cluster with nehalem processors and IB interconnect.  Does it matter if thread support level is only MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED?

Answer (score 4):

This is the script I use to launch a mixed MPI-OpenMP job. Here `n` is the number of nodes and `t` the number of threads.

```
sbatch <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=whatever
#SBATCH --threads-per-core=1
#SBATCH --nodes=$n
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=$t
#SBATCH --time=48:00:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=END
#SBATCH --mail-user=blabla@bibi.zz
#SBATCH --output=whatever.o%j

. /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
module load gcc
module unload openmpi
module load mvapich2

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$t 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/apps/eiger/Intel-CPP-11.1/mkl/lib/em64t:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

mpiexec -np $n myexe

EOF
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You typically select the number of MPI processes with `--ntasks` and the number of threads per process with `--cpu-per-task`. If you request `--ntasks=2` and `--ncpus-per-task=4`, then slurm will allocate 8 cpus either on one node, or on two nodes, four cores each, depending on resource availability and cluster configuration.

If you specify `--nodes` instead of `--ntasks`, Slurm will allocate one process per node, as if you choose `--ntask-per-node=1`.